# Does Hyperledger-Fabric provide a way to find out who (msg.sender in Ethereum) called the chaincode?

Tags: ethereum, hyperledger-fabric

In Hyperledger-Fabric how to get Ethereum like "msg.sender" in chaincode? (also when chaincode A calls chaincode B, will the "msg.sender" be script-address of A (like in Ethereum)?

Answer (score 6):

To add onto Mo-Che Chan's answer:

> ```
> func (stub *ChaincodeStub) GetCreator() ([]byte, error)
> ```
>
> GetCreator returns SignatureHeader.Creator of the signedProposal this Stub refers to.
>
> GetCreator should get signedProposal and proposal.

From the [HyperLedger blog](http://blockchain-fabric.blogspot.com/2017/04/hyperledger-fabric-v10-block-structure.html):

> The Creator field holds x.509 certificate, public key and membership
>   service provided (MSP) who issued these identity to the client. The
>   Nonce field contains some random bytes.
>
> ```
> type SignatureHeader struct {   
>     Creator []byte 
>     Nonce []byte 
> }
> ```

And from another post on the same blog, a diagram of the block structure. It has a section in each transaction (see row 4) for

Creator Identity (certificate, public key) - Client

It seems as if yes, this would be the equivalent of msg.sender in Solidity.

[image: Block structure]

Comment: Thank you for referencing the blog, I don't know how I haven't found it sooner. 
Is there a preferred/easy way to reconstruct the Creator Identity part design time (since I need to embed the content, i.e. the byte array, into the chaincode)? 
Should I concatenate some crypto materials (if so, which ones), or should I hijack an SDK request sent toward the network and extract it from that?

Answer (score 0):

```
func (stub *ChaincodeStub) GetCreator() ([]byte, error)
```

GetCreator returns SignatureHeader.Creator of the signedProposal this Stub refers to.

GetCreator should get signedProposal and proposal.

Comment: I'm more concerned about second part of my question. Paraphrasing - can chaincode act as account? (when chaincode A calls chaincode B, will the "msg.sender" be script-address of A?)